# callback function in subscribe does not work

Tags: angular

In my angular2 app, I have a call-back function to subscribe. and it should simply print every single `keyup` event happens in my `DOM`. I am sure, I have installed the `rxjs` module correctly.

Here is the code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
         `

})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(){

       var keyups= Observable.fromEvent($("#search"),"keyup");
       keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

The problem is **when I push a button nothing appears in my console**.
So what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery in your Angular2 app? Passing some mutant jQuery object as the first object to `fromEvent` won't work; I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: Be careful, one should rarely import from rxjs/Rx, unless you want to use all operators in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#search")
```

doesn't find an element because it is executed in the constructor and the element only exists when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.

This should work:

```
export class AppComponent {

    ngAfterViewInit(){

       var keyups= Observable.fromEvent($("#search"),"keyup");
       keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did someone arrange for `fromEvent` to take jQuery objects when I wasn't looking?

Comment: Don't know about jQuery.

Comment: But you used it in the code fragment you said "this should work", at least assuming his `$` is jQuery and not some alias for `getElementById`.

Comment: I just copied it from his question and fixed the for me obvious mistake, that the code is executed in the `constructor` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`. That Kamyar accepted the answer seems to indicate this made it work for him ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `keyup` event in your template like this

```
<input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

And print the value like this:

```
     onKey(event:any) {
          console.log(event.target.value);
      }
```

Comment: Well, if he wants to treat keyups as a stream which let's him do lots of cool stuff like debouncing, he should be able to. I'm sure your code will work, but what's wrong with his code?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve this problem is using @ViewChild instead of JQuery declaration.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:`
    <input #search type="text" class="form-control"  >
`
})
export class AppComponent {

@ViewChild('search') input: ElementRef

ngAfterContentInit() {
    var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, "keyup");
    keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```